# Postgres - Moving Data Folder

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, postgres-9.6

I wanted to move my PostgreSQL data folder on my Ubuntu server and I was following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04) to move it.

I was able to move it, and update my conf file to point to the new location.

When I go to run Postgres, it starts, but when I try to connect via

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

It gives me this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any ideas what happened? It says it's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After done moving PostgreSQL data directory. Don't forget to `restart` the PostgreSQL service.

Check the PostgreSQL status by command `ps -ef  | grep postgres`. -D parameter value should be new directory location.

ERROR `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` that's mean your PostgreSQL service not starting up Properly or Failed to when starting up.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I started it up, but it failed. You gave me an idea of tailing the log file in /var/log and found out that it had an issue with the data folder, and then after that I had to chmod the dir to 700.

Comment: just remember PostgreSQL data directory need 700 access permission. that mean only PostgreSQL user and root can access it. Thank you for adding this answer. and thanks for the upvote. mark as answer is good too. :)